# How to join multiple tables related by other tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm developing a site where people can publicate their houses for rent. I'm using php 5.2.0 and MySQL 5+

the publications are stored in a table like this

```
ta_publications
+---+-------------+------+
|id |    name     | date |
+---+-------------+------+
| 1 | name_001    |  ... |
| 2 | name_002    |  ... |
| 3 | name_003    |  ... |
+---+-------------+------+
```

I have diferent publications, which have "features" such as "internet", "made service", "satellite tv", etc.

These features might change in the future, and I want to be able to add/remove/modify them, so I store them in the database in a table.

```
ta_features
+---+-------------+
|id | name        |
+---+-------------+
| 1 | Internet    |
| 2 | Wi-Fi       |
| 3 | satelital tv|
+---+-------------+
```

which are related to the publications using the following table

```
ta_publication_features
+---+-------------+----------------+
|id |   type_id   | publication_id |
+---+-------------+----------------+
| 1 |      1      |       1        |
| 2 |      2      |       1        |
| 3 |      3      |       1        |
+---+-------------+----------------+
```

I think it's pretty easy to understand; There is a publication called name_001 which have internet, wi-fi and satellite tv.

I have the same data-schema for the images, I store them in this table

```
ta_images
+---+-------------+
|id | src         |
+---+-------------+
| 1 | URL_1       |
| 2 | URL_2       |
| 3 | URL_3       |
+---+-------------+
```

And use the following table to relate them to the publications

```
ta_publication_images
+---+-------------+----------------+----------+
|id |  img_id     | publication_id |   order  |
+---+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 1 |      1      |       1        |    0     |
| 2 |      2      |       1        |    1     |
| 3 |      3      |       1        |    2     |
+---+-------------+----------------+----------+
```

the column order gives the order in wich publications should be displayed when listing a single publication.

Philipp Reichart provided me with a query that will search and get all the publications that have certain features. It works for listing the publications, I can't modified it to return me the data I need.

So I figured I'll run that query and get all of the publications that pass the search criteria and then use another query to list them.

The listing of these publications shall include all publication data (everything on ta_publications)+ all of it's features + the most important (order 0) image src.

I could, for every publication, have two simple querys wich will return, separately, the most important image and all the features it has, but when listing 25 publications per page, it'll be 1 search query + (2 querys per publication * 25 publications) = 51 different querys, clearly not very efficient.

EDIT:

My question is, how can I create a SQL query that, given some publication ids, will return: all publication data (everything on ta_publications) + all of it's features + the most important (order 0) image src

Comment: Well written question since you are so new. :) +vote

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  Show what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So are you asking for a query which returns all publications, by id, including their features and top image?

Comment: LAYKE: thanks! JIM: I guess it wasn't clear, I reforumated the question. MIKE: yes. I separed the problem in two pieces. Finding the ids of the publications that match the search criteria (done) and another to select ALL the publications data, all of their features and the top img, given a list of IDs (using the ids from the first part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get redundant publication and image data with this one, but here is a way to do it with one query:

```
   SELECT p.id, p.name, p.date,
           f.id, f.name,
           i.id, i.src
    FROM ta_publications p
    JOIN ta_publication_features pf ON p.id = pf.publication_id
    JOIN ta_features f ON f.id = pf.type_id
    JOIN ta_publication_images pi ON p.id = pi.publication_id 
         AND pi.order = 0
    JOIN ta_images i ON i.id = pi.img_id
    WHERE p.id IN (  -- list of publication ids );
```

Comment: it works but gives redundant data, like you said. is there a way to avoid getting this redundant data?

Comment: No way around it, given the nature of the relation.

Comment: And what is better, performance-wise, use the search query to get the possible IDs and then use your query to get the info for the listing, removing the redundancy with PHP, or use the search query and then for each publication, do 1 query to get the IMG and a second query to get a list of all the features? This second option is way simpler an more predictable, but uses a lot of querys. I think it'll be easier to paginate with the second option. What do you think?

Comment: My advice is to try both and see what performs better! Intuitively, I think the multiple queries might be a bit quicker since it's only 2n queries and sometimes joins on a long list of tables can perform slowly - although that will depend on indexes and dbms specifics which I don't have as much experience with. The tiny performance gain (if there is one) may not be worth it for you though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Select pub.Name as [Publication], f.name as [Feature], i.name as [Image] from ta_publications pub
Join ta_publications_features pf on pf.publication_id = pub.id
Join ta_features f on f.id = pf.type_id
Join ta_publication_images pi on pi.publication_id = pub.id
Join ta_images i on i.id = pi.img_id
Where pub.id = 'appropriate id'
order by i.[order]
```

If I've followed your structure correctly this should give you the joins you need.  and you can add desired columns to the result in the select statment by adding ..  hope this helps.

Comment: you can take out the (Where pub.id = 'appropriate id') if you want all publications and since you want the top img just replace the order by whith (where i.order = 0)

Comment: for a publication with 6 features and 3 pics, it throws me 18 rows. For each pic it gives 6 rows, each one with a different feature.

Comment: adding the pi.order = 0 helps a bit the problem, it now returns a row for each feature.

Comment: Ok I get it now you need all the features as part of the same row per publication.  I believe you need to join a pivot table of all the features for a particular publication.  there may be an easier way but let me see if I can get some syntax put together for you.

Comment: I looked into what I said before and I think it is a little above me.  but I thought about it and if you are pulling the result set into an application or webservice you can parse the data there.  I believe that would be much easier and cleaner.  Sorry I couldn't find how to do it all in the query but if it were me I would do it this way.